# If the integral of a continuous function vanishes for every compact set, the function is identically zero.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, compactness

Let's consider the continuous function
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}
$$
Is it true that if $$\int_C fdx=0$$ for every compact set $C$ then the function is $f\equiv 0$?

I would say it is true, but I wouldn't know how to prove it. Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: Suppose $f(x_0) >0$ for example, can you find a non empty closed ball $\overline{B}(x_0,\epsilon)$ such that $f(x) \ge {1\over 2}f(x_0)$ on this ball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Suppose otherwise. More precisely, suppose that $f(y)>0$ for some $y\in\Bbb R^n$. So, since $f$ is continuous, for some $r>0$ we have $f(x)>\frac{f(y)}2$ for every $x\in\overline{D_r(y)}$. Therefore,$$\int_{\overline{D_r(y)}}f\geqslant\frac{f(y)}2\operatorname{vol}\left(\overline{D_r(y)}\right)>0,$$which is impossible, since $\overline{D_r(y)}$ is compact.

The case in which $f(y)<0$ is similar.

Comment: I saw you added compactness tag, but I don't see how compactness matters here (excepts that we are allowed to considers some specific ones that are balls) ? The volume is not zero because this is a ball, but compact sets can have measure zero. I have the impression this proof would work the same with an open ball.

Comment: I've added the `compactness` tag because the question specifically mentioned integration over compact sets. But what you wrote is correct, of course.